# Drag and drag netbeans java components for new LaF

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, drag-and-drop

**Background:** 
    I needed to make a modern looking appearance in my java applications. And I recently knew that the "Look and Feel" of a java application can be changed as we want. The following code example it uses something called "SubstanceOfficeSilver2007LookAndFeel" which helped me to get an rought idea about changing the "Look and Feel".

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceOfficeSilver2007LookAndFeel());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Substance Look and Feel Error", ex);
        }

        // TabbedPane border settings in substance look and feel. 
        UIManager.put(SubstanceLookAndFeel.TABBED_PANE_CONTENT_BORDER_KIND,
                TabContentPaneBorderKind.DOUBLE_PLACEMENT);

        // Cut, copy, paste menu in TextField with substance look and feel. 
        UIManager.put(LafWidget.TEXT_EDIT_CONTEXT_MENU, true);
```

This code was found in [here](http://www.devsniper.com/customers-java-swing-application-with-source-code/).

**Questions:**

1. I normally create java swing applications in NetBeans by using its drag and drop facilities; I do not code the UI of my application. My first question is can change the Look and Feel of my applications which are already made by using NetBean's drag and drop facilities.
2. Can we add those new Look and Feel components to our NetBean's palette and simply make changes in our UI by dragging and dropping them. 
   As an Example; In above code example it gives some UI like "MS Office 2007" and there will be some "tabs" and "ribbons" like "MS Office 2007".Is there a way to simply drag and drag new "Ribbon" from palette?
3. Assume that we have created a java swing application by completely coding; I mean without using NetBeans or Eclipse design view facilities. Is there a way to edit the appearance of our swing application by converting our code to a code that which is eligible for edition in Design view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not to sure about using Netbeans GUI builder to change the look and feel that
drastically.  The best option would be to code everything by hand which will give you a better understanding and loose coupling using MVC design.  I would personally if you are going after a new look and feel with modern UI is switch over to JavaFX and use scenebuilder by Gluon to customize how you want it.  Plus you can use CSS so there are no limitations.  So I would have to say for more modern looking java application nowadays use JavaFX.

Sorry if it did not help you like if it has to be in Swing or not.